# List values of fields that appear in multiple documents ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have an ElasticSearch database with documents that contain serviceName and documentId fields, like this:

Document 1:

```
{
"serviceName": 2020,
"documentId": 1
}
```

Document 2:

```
{
"serviceName": 2020,
"documentId": 2
}
```

Document 3:

```
{
"serviceName": 2019,
"documentId": 1
}
```

I need to list all serviceName values for each documentId value. So, here the answer would be:

1: 2020, 2019

2: 2020

Can this be done in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) from Elasticsearch to get your expected result.

Below is sample query:

```json
POST 74854188/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ID": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "documentId",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ServiceName": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "serviceName",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output for your sample data given in question:

```json
"aggregations": {
    "ID": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 1,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "ServiceName": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 2019,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key": 2020,
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 2,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "ServiceName": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 2020,
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

If you have defined field with `text` and `keyword` both th type then you need to use `documentId.keyword` and `serviceName.keyword`, If field is defined as `long` then above query work as it is.

Comment: Thanks Patel, this works fine, in the case when the number of documentIds is not high. However, I have over 300000 documents and 5 serviceName-s. If I limit number of documents to 10000 this works, but otherwise I get an error: "too many buckets exception -- must be less than or equal to 65535"

Comment: where you have limit number of document ? is it in top level size param or inside the aggregation ?